# Adding Children to LinearLayout and Setting Visibility

Tags: android, visibility, android-view, textview, onclicklistener

I am having a LinearLayout whose visibility is directly affected by the click of a TextView. This LinearLayout has more TextViews dynamically added inside. My LinearLayout `viewQuickLinks` starts out with a visibility of gone. In my oncreate I call `addQuickLinks` which then adds several TextViews to the LinearLayout. None of these TextViews have a set visibility. I click on the TextView to change the LinearLayout to visible and space is added, but there are no TextViews.

My xml file (just to add a note this is all in a scrollview):

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textQuickLinksTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/navigation_expand"
        android:text="@string/quick_links_title"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewQuickLinks"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Changing the LinearLayout to visible and gone:

```
private void setUpQuickLinks() {
    final TextView quickLinksTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textQuickLinksTitle);
    quickLinksTitleText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LinearLayout viewQuickLinks = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewQuickLinks);
            if (viewQuickLinks.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                viewQuickLinks.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                quickLinksTitleText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.navigation_expand, 0);
            }
            else{
                viewQuickLinks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                quickLinksTitleText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.navigation_collapse, 0);
            }
        }
    });
    quickLinksClickListeners();
}
```

Why are the TextViews not appearing when the LinearLayout is Visible?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: just to add a note ,the xml you provided cannot be in 1 Scrollview, because only 1 child view is allowed in Scrollview.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I have a ScrollView and then a LinearLayout and inside of that LinearLayout is the TextView and other LinearLayout. There are several layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `android:layout_height` to `fill_parent`. Why is it 1 dip?

Comment: Also two methods you posted are same.
And here you are making it GONE again if I understood correctly: 
`if (viewQuickLinks.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                viewQuickLinks.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: I am creating a collapsable view. So if viewQuickLinks is visible and my OnClickListener is called, then I want the viewQuickLinks to disappear, so that is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was coping and pasting without making sure that I wanted to do that. That's what I get for trying to be efficient.